# unable to populate spineer from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am unable to populate spinner from sqlite db. Can anyone please help me?

Following are my codes

**LoginDatabaseAdapter.java**

```
public List<String> GetAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  ID,category FROM CategoryMaster";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getDatabaseInstance();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String StackTrace=Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        Toast.makeText(context,lineno+StackTrace,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
}
```

**AddProduct.java**

```
private void loadSpinnerData() 
{
    try
    {

        LoginDataBaseAdapter db = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        List<String> lables = db.GetAllLabels();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        Spinnercategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stackTrace, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thank u in advance

Comment: What does your logcat say? Errors? Make sure your database class instance is created. Also check if your query is working or not, do some System.out.println(); for the strings that are returned by the cursor and you can see the output on the logcat.

Comment: i tested by using toast.my logcat not showing any errors.i am getting problem at following lines
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        Spinnercategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

After i declared spinner and getting spinner in loadSpinnerData().After that i am able to populate items in spinner